# problem reading and comparing files using nested loops

Tags: bash

```
while read newfile <&3; do   
 if [[ ! $newfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
    continue
 fi   
 #
 while read oldfile <&3; do   
 if [[ ! $oldfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
    continue
 fi   
    echo Comparing "$newfile" with "$oldfile"
    #
    if diff "$newfile" "$oldfile" >/dev/null ; then
      echo The files compared are the same. No changes were made.
    else
        echo The files compared are different.
    fi    
 done 3</infanass/dev/admin/oldfiles.txt
done 3</infanass/dev/admin/newfiles.txt
```

I think this is the right way to do nested loops.. but it doesnt quite work right.

Comment: `cmp $1 $2` is also more efficient than `diff $1 $2`.

Comment: `diff -q $1 $2` is even more efficient.

Comment: @mkrouse: Could you please be more clear about what you expect the script to do and what it does instead?

Comment: Please explain what you want it to do and what it is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use file descriptor 3 like that.

```
while read newfile do   
    if [[ ! $newfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
       continue
    fi   

    while read oldfile ; do   
       if [[ ! $oldfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
          continue
       fi   
       echo Comparing "$newfile" with "$oldfile"

       # diff -q doesn't bother generating a diff.
       # It just tells you whether or not the files match.
       if diff -q "$newfile" "$oldfile" >/dev/null ; then
         echo The files compared are the same. No changes were made.
       else
           echo The files compared are different.
       fi    
    done < /infanass/dev/admin/oldfiles.txt
done < /infanass/dev/admin/newfiles.txt
```

Assuming an empty line is a line with only whitespace on it, the empty line exception code may match non-empty lines. This will match lines with only whitespace on them (remove `\s*` to make it only match entirely empty lines):

```
if [[ ! $newfile =~ ^\s*$ ]] ; then  #empty line exception
```

Comment: Using the file descriptor 3 doesn't hurt either.. I am planning to ssh to different servers in the script.